# Am I even on the correct path with my model design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

preface: I am a newbie.

I thought I had this solved yesterday, but I am beginning to wonder if I even have a decently designed model for this domain.

I am creating a Task app (based on my job). This is my second go-round at it (with the first, I did no testing, and had bad design, although it worked). Essentially I want to add tasks which have a date, beginning and end time, gear (i.e., LCD projector), etc. Upon creating a task, I want to see if a previous task with the same room/gear exist for the current day (or previous day), and update the previous task with a note (:notes is a column) saying that a task is in the room later. I also want to check if there is a next task with the same room/gear, and want to update the current task with info about the next task. Model code pasted below:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :begin_time, :day, :end_time, :gear, :notes, :preset, :room, :setup, :strike
  before_create :initialize_linked_task_id
  before_save :check_for_adjacent_tasks

  validates :room, presence: true
  validates :begin_time, presence: true
  validates :end_time, presence: true
  validates :gear, presence: true
  validates :day, presence: true

  scope :for_day, lambda { |day| where(day: day) }
  scope :for_room, lambda { |room| where(room: room) }
  scope :with_gear, lambda { |gear| where(gear: gear) }

  private 

  def initialize_linked_task_id
    @linked_task_id = []
  end

  def check_for_adjacent_tasks
    @previous = prev?
    @next = next?

    unless @previous.nil?
      set_linked_task_id(@previous)
      @previous.update_attributes(notes: 
                              "There is a meeting in this room on #{self.day} at #{self.begin_time.strftime("%I:%M%P")}")
    end 
    unless @next.nil?
      set_linked_task_id(@next)
      self.notes = "There is a meeting in this room on #{@next.day} at #    {@next.begin_time.strftime("%I:%M%P")}"
    end
  end

  def prev?
    @prev = Task.for_day(self.day).for_room(self.room)
            .with_gear(self.gear)
            .where('begin_time < ?', self.begin_time).last
    if @prev.nil?
      @prev = Task.for_day(self.day.yesterday).for_room(self.room)
          .with_gear(self.gear).last
      return @prev unless @prev.nil?
    end

    @prev      
  end

  def next?
    @next = Task.for_day(self.day).for_room(self.room)
            .with_gear(self.gear)
            .where('begin_time > ?', self.begin_time).first
    if @next.nil?
      @next = Task.for_day(self.day.tomorrow).for_room(self.room)
          .with_gear(self.gear).first
      return @next unless @next.nil?    
    end

    @next
  end

  def set_linked_task_id(task)
    #@linked_task_id = task.id
  end
end
```

I'm not sure that I should be updating other model instances like the way I am. Should I create a Class method to update the other instances? Should I create a relationship between instances?

I also realize there's duplication in the code. But I just wanted the concept done correctly first.

**Edit**
To clarify, only the prev? method isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Rails! You'll have a better shot at getting an answer if you can try to ask some more specific questions. Perhaps rather than put a big broad question like this on SO, you might consider breaking this up into several small questions, like: how best to create a next/previous record method in Rails? You are more likely to find existing articles that would help you searching that was as well.

Comment: Fair enough. But that's what I was shooting for when I said, "I'm not sure that I should be updating other model instances like the way I am. Should I create a Class method to update the other instances? Should I create a relationship between instances?" I should have been more clear about that. Thank you.